# Look for characters in a specific location of 2D array with pointers

Tags: c

I have been playing around with pointers and arrays and I have successfully come up with this code that does what I intend to.
The following code looks for a specific character in a specific location of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int arraySize = 5;
    int location = 2;

    char arr[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }; 
    char *ptr = arr; //same as char *ptr = &arr[0]

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (ptr[location] == 'c')
        {
            printf("found");
            i = arraySize + 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to try to find a specific character in a 2D array and I do not fully understand the process of how to do it, I had researched a bit but I am not really sure how to search for it.

I have written a partial code and I believe that I will need to add a second for loop to iterate through the other direction of the array. Although it does not work as I believe I have to modify the pointer but not too sure how.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int arraySize = 5;
    int location = 2;
    int location2 = 2;

    char arr[5][5] = { {'a','b','c','d','e'}, {'g','h','c','j','k'} }; 
    char *ptr = arr;

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
        {
            if (ptr[location][location2] == 'c')
            {
                printf("found");
                i = arraySize + 1 ;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have little knowledge of coding so please be patient! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The loops in both of these cases are completely pointless. The location being inspected in either code is unmodified. Either you find what you're looking for every time, or never, *repeatedly*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Do you mean something like `if (ptr[i] + j == 'g')`

Comment: To make the second compile, `ptr` should be `char (*ptr)[5] = arr;` Doesn't change what I said earlier, however, and to be honest, `location`, `location2`, and `ptr` are all pretty worthless in this code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your programs:

- you test if `ptr[location] == 'c'` but you should instead use index `i`:

  ```
    if (ptr[i] == 'c')
  ```
- you cause the loop to exit by patching the loop index variable `i` with `i = arraySize + 1;` This is considered sloppy, confusing and error prone. You should just use a `break` statement.

In your code, there is no need for a pointer, but if you pass the array to a function, this function will receive a pointer to the first element of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_char(char *ptr, int size, char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (ptr[i] == ch) {
            printf("found '%c' at index %d\n", ch, i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }; 
    int arraySize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

    if (!find_char(arr, arraySize, 'c')) {
        printf("not found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The case of a 2D array is more tricky: if you pass the array to a function, the argument must be defined as a pointer to an array of arrays. There are 2 ways to specify such a pointer:

- as a pointer to an array of arrays of a fixed size:

  ```
  int find_char(int rows, char (*ptr)[5], char ch)
  ```
- as a pointer to an array of arrays of a specified variable size: this possibility was added in C99 but is not supported by all compilers:

  ```
  int find_char(int rows, int cols, char (*ptr)[cols], char ch)
  ```

Here is a modified version using this C99 approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_char(int rows, int cols, char (*ptr)[cols], char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (ptr[i][j] == ch) {
                printf("char '%c' was found at array[%d][%d]\n", ch, i, j);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char arr[][5] = { { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
                      { 'g', 'h', 'c', 'j', 'k' } }; 
    int rows = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    int cols = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(*arr[0]);

    if (!find_char(rows, cols, arr)) {
        printf("not found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful here. A 2D array in C is an *array-of-arrays*. Meaning `arr[x][y]` is an array of `x` arrays of `y` elements each. This is important for pointer use with 2D arrays.

In C, when an array is accessed, it is converted to a pointer to the first element. See [C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2). So when you access `arr` in your code, it is converted to a pointer to the first *array*.

What type is the pointer? It is a *pointer-to-array-of* `char[5]`. A *pointer-to-array* `char[5]` named `ptr` is declared:

```c
char (*ptr)[5];
```

(**note:** the parenthesis ARE important. Due to operator-precedence `[ ]` has higher precedence, so if declared `char *ptr[5];` you do not have a *pointer-to-array*, but instead have an *array-of-pointers*. Adding the parenthesis around `(*ptr)` specifies the type *pointer* is evaluated before `[ ]` resulting in a *pointer-to-array*)

In order to access a specific character in the i<sup>th</sup> array in `arr`, you can use `ptr[i][j]` (which is equivalent to `*(*(ptr + i) + j)`, but is the preferred form for readability). You can also simply declare and use a separate pointer to access each element of the i<sup>th</sup> array, such as `char *p = ptr[i];`

How does the type work? Recall, `ptr` is a *pointer-to-array*. The `[ ]` acts as a dereference of the pointer just as `*ptr` would. (technically `*ptr` is `*(ptr + 0)` or in preferred form `ptr[0]`). So when you dereference `ptr` to get the i<sup>th</sup> array, the resulting type will be `char [5]`. Since it is an array type, on access [6.3.2.1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2) applies resulting in the type being *pointer-to* `char`.

Putting it altogether, and using an additional index on `ptr` to access each character, and allowing you to specify the character to search for as the first argument to your program (default `'c'` if no argument is given), you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ASIZE 5   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char arr[][ASIZE] = { {'a','b','c','d','e'},    /* 2D array of char */
                          {'g','h','c','j','k'} }, 
         (*ptr)[ASIZE] = arr,                       /* pointer to array */
         find = argc > 1 ? *argv[1] : 'c';          /* char to find */
    int nrows = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr,           /* no. of rows */
        found = 0;                                  /* found flag */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {               /* loop over arrays */
        for (int j = 0; j < ASIZE; j++) {           /* loop over chars */
            if (ptr[i][j] == find) {                /* compare */
                printf ("found '%c' in array %d within arr\n", find, i + 1);
                found = 1;                          /* set found flag */
                goto done;                          /* break nested loops */
            }
        }
    }
    done:;
    
    if (!found) { /* handle char not found */
        printf ("character '%c' - not in arr\n", find);
    }
}
```

(**note:** the only way to directly break nested loops is to use the `goto` statement)

As mentioned above, the pointer notation equivalence can be used for the comparison. So the following is equivalent (just harder to read):

```c
            if (*(*(ptr + i) + j) == find) {        /* compare */
```

Often, it is simpler to use a separate pointer to iterate over the objects in the row-arrays. A quick rewriting of the loops can be done as follows:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {               /* loop over arrays */
        char *p = ptr[i];
        for (; p < ptr[i] + ASIZE; p++) {           /* loop over chars */
            if (*p == find) {                       /* compare */
                printf ("found '%c' in array %d within arr\n", find, i + 1);
                found = 1;                          /* set found flag */
                goto done;                          /* break nested loops */
            }
        }
    }
    done:;
```

Which from C99 on allows you to declare the loop variable within the loop declaration allowing you to rewrite the loop as:

```c
        /* loop over chars */
        for (char *p = ptr[i]; p < ptr[i] + ASIZE; p++) {
            ...
        }
```

**Example Use/Output**

Regardless of which notation you use, the results are the same, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/findcharin2Darr
found 'c' in array 1 within arr
```

If the requested character isn't in the array:

```
$ ./bin/findcharin2Darr f
character 'f' - not in arr
```

Or locating a character in the second row:

```
$ ./bin/findcharin2Darr g
found 'g' in array 2 within arr
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.